# Emacs Gnus Faces (Fonts)

Tags: emacs, gnus, emacs-faces

The *slrn* newsreader has an attractive interface with different colours for the author, subject and date columns when browsing list of articles in a newsgroup. I am looking for the Emacs font/face variables for these fields in gnus, but have not been able to find them. The gnus manual for [faces](http://www.gnus.org/manual/gnus_290.html#SEC290) does not list the available faces and none of the faces list in Emacs (`M-x` `customize-face` `gnus-`... looks relevant. I am using gnus 5.13 in Emacs 23.2.1.

(This question is not related to displaying "faces" (icons/avatars) in Emacs or gnus.)

**Solved:** See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format string for various elements in gnus can be customized by modifying the appropriate [variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Formatting-Variables.html#Formatting-Variables). The variable for the summary line is `gnus-summary-format-line`. I am not using the [default](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Summary-Buffer-Lines.html) value for this variable, but instead am using the value `%U%R%z %(%&user-date;  %-15,15f %* %B%s%)\n`.

As described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Formatting-Fonts.html#Formatting-Fonts), a new face can be applied to any (sub)section of a format line by bracketing the section with `%1{` and `%}`, where the `1` in this example corresponds to `gnus-face-1`. `gnus-face-1` in my installation defaults to "italics", so adding the following to my `~/.emacs` file results in the author in the summary line appearing in italics:

`(setq gnus-summary-line-format "%U%R%z %(%&user-date;  %1{%-15,15f%} %* %B%s%)\n")`

Answer (score 2):

I think they're scattered a bit in the gnus codebase. The faces used in the article buffer are probably in gnus-art.el, etc.

It sounds like your biggest problem is that there are specific faces that you can't find the symbol for. You can always do `M-x describe-face` to see what is under the cursor to solve that problem.

Also, `(face-list)` returns a list of all defined faces. You could scan that list looking for things that look like likely candidates for the particular faces you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks. `M-x` `describe-face` returns the same value (gnus-summary-normal-unread), so only one face is used for the whole line.

Answer (score 1):

I go with `M-x list-faces-display` (which opens a new buffer with all the currently defined face variables fontified to the color that they're set to, in alphabetic order) when I want to see what faces I need to change to get a mode working.

Then I `setq` them, using either the format from `color-theme` or from the new emacs built-in theme format, depending on which version of emacs I'm in.